# On Genealogy & Family History, the left column in the profile settings is suddenly appearing in Russian instead of English

Tags: bug, status-completed, preferences

It's all Greek to me.

Or rather, Russian. Behold my profile preferences:

[image: sidebar of Preferences page is Russian, while the rest is English]

How do I fix this? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Which site(s)? I can't reproduce, but on [ru.so] I do have the reverse problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl5HO.jpg

Comment: @Glorfindel From the screenshot's colors, it appears to be Russian Language in Russian.  That said, on *that* site, I get the same behavior as you: the sidebar is in English.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog wait, I recognize the site icon now, it's [Genealogy.SE].

Comment: To the author: it would have been nice if you'd included details on the report, such as the site you're experiencing it on, in your initial post. I got your sites mixed up and I'm certain the staff would have been confused as well.

Comment: Yup, this one's on me. We're on it! I'll answer once the fix is out.

Comment: @BenKelly Is the bug Glorfindel mentioned above where the English sidebar appears on Russian sites included in the above fix as well? Also, can this please get a [tag:status-planned]?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The site is in the title...

Comment: If you want to be pedantic: my comment mentions that *you* should be the one to include details, and they should be in the *initial* post (i.e. revision 1).

Comment: Sorry, @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, I assumed it wasn't site specific -- Genealogy etc. isn't so important to be targeted by individual bugs!

Comment: I don't see a problem :) Doesn't everyone know Russian these days?

Comment: @AntonMenshov English, French, German, Latinate languages... Will add Russian to my list, but a little after Chinese, I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you for the report. A fix has been committed and is now live.

The root cause of the issue was due to (drumroll please)... caching! As part of some work done to prepare the user profile settings nav for a responsive design, I introduced a bit of code to bring this very old area up-to-date with how we create settings navigations on other parts of the site. Part of this change is the ability to cache how the navigation is built, which will give us a bit of a performance boost on the server side of things.

Now, this is all well and good, except I also included the text strings in this cached object `:facepalm:`. This meant that the very first site to cache the built settings nav also cached the text *in that site's language*. The result is that when you visit another site, it'll also show the nav in the cached language. In other words, if the first site request that hit the server since the change rolled out was a Russian-language site, it would show in Russian for everyone in all site requests against that server; similarly, if the first site request that hit that server since the change was an English-language site, it would show in English even on the international sites.

The fix was pretty simple - don't cache the text as a string, but instead as a getter function that fetches the correct value at runtime.

Comment: There are only two sites of 178 that language is Russian, hence the probability of choosing such site is just ~1%. Or it's all actions of Russian hackers.